# Is there a time oracle for a Solidity calendar library?

Tags: solidity, oracles

According to the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units):

> Take care if you perform calendar calculations using these units, because not every year equals 365 days and not even every day has 24 hours because of leap seconds. Due to the fact that leap seconds cannot be predicted, an exact calendar library has to be updated by an external oracle.

Who is updating solidity? Where is this located?

Comment: It means that for the EVM each day has exactly 24 * 60 * 60 seconds so for days with leap seconds it won't match the number of "real life" seconds.

If your dapp requires handling of real life seconds then you have to use an specialized library and/or oracle.

Unfortunately I'm not aware of the existence of such library with that purpose. If you need you could make query to a leap seconds site with an existing oracle like chainlink.

Comment: Oh so there is no such library that currently does this? And if I use the year keyword it will fall more and more out of alignment in my smart contract?

Comment: At least I've never heard of such library. I won't use year as unit because it is always 365, even on leap years! If your contract expect that EVM seconds == "real life" seconds then they will slowly get apart. I don't think leap seconds is a problem for most contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no solidity time oracle.

`year` just always means 365 days, even on leap years!

So if you write a contract that lasts many years, be sure to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such library for time or calendar.
Best way to handle time is just you should handle it in seconds. with "block.timestamp". you can get current time for blockchain by unix epoch. https://www.epochconverter.com/

Note: Might be you find some difference between epoch time and "block.timestamp" time  about 1 minute or few seconds